# Formatting text as you type in the text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a policy number that should be in format "XX-YY-123456". I am working on a formatter that should format automatically in above format as the user types in the policy number or copy/paste it. Need help in modifying the below code to suit my requirement.

```
$('.policynumber').bind("change keyup input",function() { 
    foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens 
    foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,3}', 'g')).join("-");
    $(this).val(foo);
});
```

The above code works fine if I have to put dashes every 3 characters.

Comment: Have a google for an 'input masking' library. There are lots already available that will do this for you

Comment: I tried googling. Most of the stuff I am finding is for fixed length as the above code works and puts dashes every 3 characters. Also, the above code works perfectly for typing as well as copy pasting the contents. It would be a great help if someone could help me modify this code for my needs

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) takes a custom mask. `aa-aa-999999` would work in your case

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Regex according to format :

```
"1234567890".match(/\d{2}(?=\d{6})|\d+/g).join("-")
```

You need to change in code like this :

```
  $('.policynumber').bind("change keyup input",function() { 
        foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens 
        foo = foo.match(/\d{2}(?=\d{6})|\d+/g).join("-");
        $(this).val(foo);
    });
```